# I've a very noobish inquiry about an issue with a display

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
   package walmart.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class WalmartActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        EditText name;
        Button search;
    TextView display;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             setContentView(R.layout.main);   
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);

                search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

                display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);



                name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                name.setText("");
                        }
                });
                search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                               if (name.equals("Electronics")) {
                                display.setText ('5');
                           } else if (name.equals("candy")) {
                                   display.setText ('1');
                           } else if (name.equals("Tobacco")) {
                               display.setText ("1");
                           } 
        }});
};}
```

No matter what i do, nothing shows up in my output.  I'm very, very new to JAVA, so I can't seem to find out why nothing's showing up on my display.

*edit* Edited my code to what i currently have. Still not working.

Comment: I can only see half your code.  Can you post the whole thing?  Also, can you be more specific about what your code is *supposed* to do?

Comment: Edit: android tag added. OP, you should do this yourself next time as it is a key tag for your problem.

Comment: I could post the whole thing, but it's really just a whole bunch of if then statements and rather long.  But to asnwer you, it's supposed to take a name entered and turn it into a numerical output in the display. [Named display in the text]

Comment: So your activity is being created with the buttons, but your onclick listeners arent working?

Comment: I'd suppose so. I'm not sure what the problem exactly is, but i put in a phrase into the EditText, and all i get is nothing in the display box.

Comment: What is the display box? you have no View attached to it....is it a text view in your layout?

Comment: To me `String display` just looks like a string that you are updating but it is not attached to anything. If you have a TextView in your layout, you could set that as the display and update that

Comment: Yeah, the display box is just a display view. I tried updating it as well as some of my if/thens to something like else if (name.equals("candy")) {
                                       System.out.println ("1");
                               } , but still, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that code, the issue might be with how you are initializing name and search.

Change your code:

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("etName", "id", getPackageName()));
search = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btnSearch", "id", getPackageName()));
```

to this:

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
```

Also, add a TextView to display your answer into your `main.xml` file, give it an id (let's say display for example) `android:id="@+id/display"` and then add it to your activity so you can change it:

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

and then you can update it by calling:

```
display.setText('some text');
```

Thus the start of your file should look like this:

```
public class WalmartActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText name;
    Button search;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        ....
```

Next update your `if` statements from:

```
if (name.equals("Electronics"))
```

to:

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("Electronics")) {
    display.setText("something");
}
```

An example piece of code:

Demo2Activity.java

```
package com.demo1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Demo2Activity extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText.getText().toString().equals("Electronics")) {
                    textView.setText("found");
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="main2.xml"
        android:id="@+id/textText" />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still not doing it, sadly. :/

Comment: Referring to my comment in your question, what are you updating? if Display is what you are expecting to appear on your screen, from what I see above it wont happen

Comment: I update the formatting on my if-thens.  I'm not sure if there's anything else i should be doing, but if there is, let me know.

Comment: That's basically what my code looks like.  See my main post for what i currently have.

Comment: Then i get 'Incompatible operand types Editable and String' as an error when i do that.

Comment: its definately your if statements. Im just looking at why its not working

Comment: Ok that works and I have tested it...I always forget you have to use `.equals()` to compare strings and not `==`. too much javascript and perl :S

Comment: It would also be best to use CONSTANTS instead of hardcoding strings into your code

Comment: I'm not sure how i'd do that, but i'm still coming up with nothing. >_<

Comment: Apparently, if i use single quotes, the entire thing crashes.  That's progress?

Comment: I created a simple app that does the same thing and it works. Ill add the code to my answer

Comment: look at your code `name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener..` change it to what I have

Comment: No problems, I missed the onclick listener, as I do mine a much simpler way through XML in two lines of code, so I get a bit rusty with the java implementation :S